# How to merge different dataframes of the same observation with different names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have three data frames. The first data frame `df_1` is the baseline data frame, the rest of the data frames contains information that I want to add to the matching observations of df_1 The problem is that the observations don't have the same names I have a fourth data frame with the corresponding name on each variable. I want to recognize those values that have matching observations in the rest of the data frames to get a single data frame with all the observations.

```
set.seed(123)
# I have three dataframes
a <- rnorm(6, 3, 2)
b <- rnorm(6, 1, 3)
c <- rpois(6, 3)
year <- c(rep(2014, 6))
player <- c("Aaron Badaley", "Andrew Loupe", "Ben Crane", "Ben Curtis", "Ben Martin", "Brendon de Jonge")

df_1 <- data.frame(player, year, a, b, c)

d <- rnorm(3, 3, 2)
e <- rnorm(3, 1, 3)
f <- rpois(3, 3)
year <- c(rep(2014, 3))
player <- c("Andrew Loupe IV", "Ben Crane", "Brendon de Jonge")

df_2 <- data.frame(player, year, d, e, f)

g <- rnorm(4, 3, 2)
h <- rnorm(4, 1, 3)
i <- rpois(4, 3)
year <- c(rep(2014, 4))
player <- c("Aron Badelay", "Ben Crane 3", "Brendon de Jonge", "Ben Curt")

df_3 <- data.frame(player, year, g, h, i)

a_to_c <- c("Aaron Badaley", "CT", "Andrew Loupe", "Ben Crane","Brendon de Jonge", "Ben Curtis", "Ben Martin")
d_to_f <- c("Aron Badaley", "C.T.", "Andrew Loupe", "Ben Crane","Brendon de Jonge", "Ben Curt", "Ben")
g_to_i <- c("Aron Badelay", "CT", "Andrew Loupe", "Ben Crane 3","Brendon de Jonge", "Ben Curt", "Ben Martin")

names_palyer <- data.frame(a_to_c, d_to_f, g_to_i)
```

These are the three data frames. They are of different lengths. There are names, years, and variables. For this example, there is only one year but in reality, there are more years and I have thousands of observations. The main problem is that not all observations containing in df_1 have a matching observation with df_2 or/and df_3 but all observations in `df_2` and `df_3`should be inside `df_1`. The matching data frame has more observations than all the data frames since this is like a dictionary for names.

This is what I tried to do:

```
out <- data.table::copy(df_1)
for(i in 1:(ncol(names_palyer)-1)) {
  tmp <- data.table::copy(get(paste0('df_', i + 1)))
  keydat <- names_palyer[c(i, i + 1)]
  keydat <- keydat[keydat[[2]] %in% tmp$player,, drop = FALSE]
  i1 <- match(keydat[[2]], tmp$player, nomatch = 0) 
  
  tmp$player[i1] <- keydat[[1]]
  print(tmp)
  out <- merge(out, tmp, by = c('player', 'year'), all.x = TRUE)
  i2 <- match(keydat[[1]], out$player, nomatch = 0)
  
  out$player[i2] <- keydat[[2]][keydat[[1]] %in% out$player] 
}

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
split.default(out[-(1:2)], sub("\\..*", "", names(out)[-(1:2)])) %>%
  map_dfc(reduce, coalesce)  %>% 
  bind_cols( out[1:2], .)
```

This output doesn't work since does not recognize the observations that are present in df_1 and df_3 but not inside df_2.

This is the output I need:

```
head(out,1)
         player year        a        b c  d  e  f     g       h i
1 Aaron Badaley 2014 1.879049 2.382749 4 NA NA NA 0.829 -2.4966 1
```

Comment: You are using the earlier code in your previous post.  Have you tried the updated one (which is working without any warning for the example)

Comment: Hi Akrun. Good to hear from you. Thanks for your help!. Yes. If you can try with this one. I change and now show different output. I think the problem was it recognizes only the matching observation in the three dataframes. But when the observation are only in two dataframes do not reconigze the observations to merge the dataframes

Comment: I get `dim(out)#
[1]  6 11` with this example.  The code is working by merging between datasets passed as sequence i.e. in the first loop, it merges df_1, with df_2, then in the second the merged output of df_1 and df_2 with df_3 based on player.  Before doing the merge, we are changing the player in the incoming data i..e the new data 'df_2' and 'df_3' in the loop based on the names_palyer columns

Comment: Yes. That's true. The code works, however it doesn't give the expected results. Check the first row: Aaron Badaley in df_1 is not present in df_2 and its name is Aron Badelay in df_3. But in the out data frame he has no observations for df_3

Comment: Can you use set.seed for creating example so that it is easier to know the expected (along with expected output) thanks

Comment: I update the code. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: the logic used in the code doesn't work anymore because in the second data, you don't have any Aaron Badaley or Aron Badaley.  So, when we go into the third data, , there is Aron Badaley, but the 'out' created have the value 'Aaron Badaley'.  Our assignments are based on updating two columns each of names_palyer data.  In that last round, 2nd 3rd column of names_palyer have only Aron Badaley

Comment: Now it works. Thanks for all your help!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are making the change to first column index, it seems to work

```
out <- data.table::copy(df_1)
for(i in 1:(ncol(names_palyer)-1)) {
  tmp <- data.table::copy(get(paste0('df_', i + 1)))
  keydat <- copy(names_palyer)
  keydat <- keydat[keydat[[i+1]] %in% tmp$player,, drop = FALSE]
  
  i1 <- match(keydat[[i + 1]], tmp$player, nomatch = 0) 
 
  
  tmp$player[i1] <- keydat[[1]]
 
  out <- merge(out, tmp, by = c('player', 'year'), all.x = TRUE)
  i2 <- match(keydat[[1]], out$player, nomatch = 0)
  
  #out$player[i2] <- keydat[[i+1]][keydat[[1]] %in% out$player] 
}
```

-checking

```
out[1, ]
#         player year        a        b c  d  e  f         g         h i
#1 Aaron Badaley 2014 1.879049 2.382749 4 NA NA NA 0.8286017 -2.496635 1
```

---

Or may be we could bind the rows together and change the 'player' name and then grouped by 'player' replace the column values with the non-NA value

```
bind_rows(df_1, df_2, df_3 ) %>% 
    mutate(player = recode(player, !!! setNames(names_palyer[[1]], names_palyer[[2]]) )) %>%
    group_by(player, year) %>% 
    mutate(across(a:f, ~ .[complete.cases(.)][1])) %>%
    mutate(player = recode(player, !!! setNames(names_palyer[[1]], names_palyer[[3]]))) %>% 
    group_by(player, year) %>%
    mutate(across(a:i, ~ .[complete.cases(.)][1])) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    distinct 
# A tibble: 7 x 11
#  player            year     a      b     c      d      e     f      g       h     i
#  <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
#1 Aaron Badaley     2014  1.88  2.38      4 NA     NA        NA  0.829 -2.50       1
#2 Andrew Loupe      2014  2.54 -2.80      4 NA     NA        NA NA     NA         NA
#3 Ben Crane         2014  6.12 -1.06      3  4.00  -0.418     2  2.83  -1.46       2
#4 Ben Curtis        2014  3.14 -0.337     3 NA     NA        NA  2.71   0.0398     4
#5 Ben Martin        2014  3.26  4.67      2 NA     NA        NA NA     NA         NA
#6 Brendon de Jonge  2014  6.43  2.08      1 -0.933 -2.20      1  5.14   3.05       2
#7 Andrew Loupe IV   2014 NA    NA        NA  6.57   3.10      2 NA     NA         NA
```

Comment: The code works really well. Just one more thing. When there is the same observation player in different years the code only merges the dataset for the first one. For example take Aaron Badaley, if I have another Aaron Badaley in df_1 for 2015 and it has observation matching in df_2 and df_3 those are not incorporated into the out data frame. I can make it work by filtering the data for each year and it works good but there is another way to do it easier?

Comment: @PastorSoto It is just that your framework used should be better one i.e. generally a keyval dataset have only two columns, key column and value column makes it easier.  But your case is complicated with different names in different files and that makes the mapping difficult because once you merge, we have to match the names of player with the merged data

Comment: @PastorSoto Now, we have a case where there are difference in names for 'dates'

Comment: @PastorSoto without making much change in this, may be spliting by 'year' and then do a second loop may work

Comment: Yes! It is difficult than I thought. Thank you so much for helping me with this. How can I use split with a second loop?

Comment: @PastorSoto does all the dataset have all years

Comment: No. df_1 has from 2014 to 2021; df_2 has from 2014 to 2020, and df_3 from 2014 to 2021.

Comment: @PastorSoto can you check the solution update with a different way